# filtering of values in list based on values in set

Tags: java, java-8

I'm trying to use java 8 to solve the following issue. Say I have the following (`A` and `B` are custom classes)

```
ArrayList<A> skills;
HashSet<B> workCenters;
```

What I need to do is to find whether value `a.getDepartment()` which is a `String` also contained in `B` which also has a method `String getDepartment()` and then to collect those into new `List<A>`.

I tried such:

```
 List<A> collect = skills.stream()
     .filter(s -> workCenters.contains(s.getDepartment())
     .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

but in this case i don't do it right because I couldn't retrieve `getDepartment()` from `workCenters`. What would be the correct solution?

Comment: you show way to little code for us to try to figure this one out

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could start with converting `HashSet<B>` to `HashSet<String>` and then use your code:

```
Set<String> bDeps = workCenters.stream()
                               .map(B::getDepartment)
                               .collect(Collectors.toSet());

List<A> collect = skills.stream()
                         .filter(s -> bDeps.contains(s.getDepartment()))
                         .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 6):

1. `collect` all the department in `workCenters` into a `Set<String>`let's say `departmentSet`.
2. ```
   List<A> collect = skills.stream()
                           .filter(s -> departmentSet.contains(s.getDepartment())
                           .collect(Collectors.toList());
   ```

Answer (score 5):

First stream over the `workCenters` and get the set of departments in there, then stream over the skills and filter out any ones not present in that set.

```
final Set<String> workCenterDepartments = workCenters.stream()
    .map(B::getDepartment)
    .collect(Collectors.toSet());

final List<A> skillsWithWorkCenterDept = skills.stream()
    .filter(skill -> workCenterDepartments.contains(skill.getDepartment()))
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

If you don't need the old list any more, you might decide to remove elements from the previous list rather than create a new one:

```
skills.removeIf(skill -> !workCenterDepartments.contains(skill.getDepartment()));
```

Answer (score 1):

```
List<B> workCenters = Collections.emptyList();
List<A> skills = Collections.emptyList();

Set<String> workCenterDepartments = workCenters.stream().map(B::getDepartment).collect(Collectors.toSet());
List<A> skillsWithWorkCenterDept = new ArrayList<>(skills);
skillsWithWorkCenterDept.removeIf(skill -> !workCenterDepartments.contains(skill.getDepartment()));
```